# git push bare master : FATAL not a git repository

Tags: git, github, git-bare

I’m currently working on a cloud synced feature for my notes using git (+git-crypt) based on the article of [Rene Schallner](https://renerocks.ai/blog/obsidian-encrypted-github-android/).

I've a directory named **Example** in which there is :

- Example_laptop (my current repo/notes file)
- Example_bak (as a backup/copy file)
- git-crypt-key (that i've exported by cmd for the further encryption of my repo)

Example_laptop is my repo folder, my notes in Markdown were already there so while in this dir path i did `git init`, then i set up my `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` (i also config `oh-my-zsh`), and finally i put my files into "staging" with `git add` then commit `git commit -m '.'`.

I was on the step of **setting up a remote repo for testing the config** as suggested in the article, i created a bare directory in "root" (Home/usr).

```
$ cd
$ mkdir bare
$ cd bare
$ git init --bare
```

Then i go back to the repo folder (Example_laptop) and added the bare directory `git remote add bare ../bare`

But then, when I try `git push bare master` I get :

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

When I do `git status` in the path *Example/Example_laptop* I get :

```
on branch master, nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I couldn’t access any repo on my GitHub account

I set up and makes change on git config -global for both username and email

Comment: Your relative path looks wrong: `cd` takes you to your home directory, so you'll have `$HOME/bare` as the bare repository (but it's wise to name these with `.git` as an extension, just for sanity). Meanwhile you `cd $HOME/Example/Example_laptop`. So the *relative* path from here to `bare.git` is `../../bare`. It may be easier to use the *absolute* path: `git remote add bare $HOME/bare`.

Comment: Yes at first it thought it was a credential issue but it should be a problem relative to the path as you say, so you're meaning that the position of the bare directory might be the problem ?

Comment: Also when creating the bare directory it doesn't name the folder with a .git extension so it must be rename after creating it right ? and if i had to use the absolute path do we agree that i could use `pwd` when i'm in the bare directory then copy&paste the path in the cmd `git remote add bare "path"/bare` just to make sure the path is correct. Also i have already add the bare to that uncorrect path do i have to undo it before doing it with the right path and if yes HOW ?

Comment: Well, generally you can run `git init --bare foo.git` to create a new bare `foo.git` repository here, or `git init --bare bare/xyzzy.git` to create `xyzzy.git` in the existing directory `bare`. It can't be a credential issue when using local path names as Git itself does no authentication and has no use for credentials: Git just has *helpers* to send them through to https if/when needed.

Comment: To fix the "url" (path) of an existing remote, use `git remote set-url`, or use `git remote remove` once to remove the existing remote, then `git remote add` to create a new but different remote with the same name. (The set-url method is shorter and easier here.)

Comment: I don't know if it useful to say it but i'm running on Linux Lubuntu and the  `cd` cmd bring me back to `/home/myname`, also my file where i create the repo is in this path `$HOME/myname/Documents/Example/Example_laptop` @torek

Comment: Ah, well, if you're that deep, it's more `../` steps to reach `$HOME`. I just assumed you were in `$HOME/Example/Example_laptop` to get the "climb up twice", but given that path you'd have to climb up three times (1 to Example, 1 to Documents, 1 to myname—presumably you mean `$HOME` or `/home/myname` but not `$HOME/myname` which would be `/home/myname/myname`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237475/discussion-between-jawad-bounaas-and-torek).